Sign of the sum of alternating triple binomial coefficient
I encountered a research question and it can be turned equivalently into showing
$$\sum_{k=j}^n(-1)^{k+j}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}\Big(\frac{1}{10n+10}\Big)^k\binom{2k}{k+j}\ge0$$
holds for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $0\le j\le n$; I have reason to believe this is true since I directly calculated it for various $j,n$ up to about $n=70$.
I've tried a lot of attempts; one of the observations is that for a fixed pair of $(j,n)$, the maximum value of $\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}\Big(\frac{1}{n+1}\Big)^k\binom{2k}{k+j}$ always happens around $k\le j+5$, i.e. during the one of the initial terms; after that the value of $\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}\Big(\frac{1}{n+1}\Big)^k\binom{2k}{k+j}$ drastically decreases and becomes nearly negligible compare to the several initial terms. I'm not exactly sure how to use this to prove my desired result though.
Another method I tried was the Egorychev method; specifically I found that it's similar to the first example on the wiki page. However, the existence of the $\binom{2k}{k+j}$ terms makes the residue extremely complicated, so that the result this method gives doesn't seem to have any simplification compare to the original expression.
Genearlized hypergeometric function seems to be another possible direction but I didn't find any helpful/related sources.
Any suggestions, solutions, or related paper recommendations would be really appreciated!

Like many questions about "sums of binomial coefficients" this can be answered by writing the sums as hypergeometric functions (which is what they are) and looking up the answer in the literature.
Using the notation in the answer of T. Amdeberhan, we have
$$f_{n,j}(x)=\frac{(n+j)!}{j!j!(n-j)!}\,{}_3F_2\left(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{j+1/2,j+n+1,j-n}{j+1,2j+1};4x\right).$$
We can apply Clausen's identity, 16.12.2 in
DLMF §16.12, to write this as a square of a ${}_2F_1$-series. The result becomes neater after an application of identity 15.8.1 in
DLMF §15.8. We find that
$$f_{n,j}(x)=\frac{(n+j)!}{j!j!(n-j)!}(1-4x)^{n-j}\,{}_2F_1\left(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{(j-n)/2,(j-n+1)/2}{j+1};\frac{4x}{4x-1}\right)^2,$$
which proves the conjecture of Amdeberhan and answers your question.
Incidentally, Clausen's identity plays a role in the proof of the Bieberbach conjecture, see references given in the comments.

very nice example of collaborative work

@Hjalmar: It would help your last comment if you are able to add a direct reference to the Bieberbach conjecture.

@T.Amdeberhan The original reference is L. de Branges, A proof of the Bieberbach conjecture, Acta Math. 154 (1985), 137–152. De Branges needs an inequality proved in R. Askey and G. Gasper, Positive Jacobi polynomial sums. II. Amer. J. Math. 98 (1976), 709–737. The proof of that inequality uses Clausen's identity. A simpler proof, still based on Clausen's identity, is in G. Gasper, A short proof of an inequality used by de Branges in his proof of the Bieberbach, Robertson and Milin conjectures, Complex Variables Theory Appl. 7 (1986), 45–50.

@HjalmarRosengren: thanks, I posted this with your answer so that it is immediately accessible to the reader.

@T.Amdeberhan It was just a minor comment. The only reason I mentioned it is that not that many people know hypergeometric identities by name. Pointing out that it is the same identity that is behind de Branges's theorem will help people to recognize it.

Since the references to papers about the Bieberbach conjecture are not directly relevant to the question it seemed misleading to include them in the answer, so I removed them.

@HjalmarRosengren: I undesrtand.

This is not an answer but a conjecture.
Let $x:=\frac1{10n+10}$. Also the OP's claim is not altered with the (harmless) substitution of $x^k$ by $x^{k-j}$. Anyways, it suffices to prove that
$$f_{n,j}(x):=\sum_{k=j}^n(-x)^{k-j}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}\binom{2k}{k+j}\geq 0.$$
Conjecture. There exist positive integers $a_{n,j}$ and polynomials $P_{n,j}(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that
$$f_{n,j}(x)
=\begin{cases} a_{n,j}\cdot P_{n,j}(x)^2 \qquad &\text{if $n-j$ is even} \\ 
a_{n,j}(1-4x)P_{n,j}(x)^2 \qquad &\text{if $n-j$ is odd.}
\end{cases}$$
In particular, $f_{n,j}(x)\geq 0$ since $x\leq\frac14$.
The OP asked about the factor $1-4x$: we show $f_{n,j}(\frac14)=0$ whenever $n-j$ is odd. To this end, we need to employ Wilf–Zeilberger's methodology. Define the two functions,
\begin{align*}
F_j(n,k)&:=\left(-\frac14\right)^{k-j}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n+k}{k}\binom{2k}{k+j}(n+j+1)!(n-j+1)!, \\
G_j(n,k)&:=-2F_j(n,k)\cdot \frac{k(2n+3)(k^2-j^2)((n+3)^2-j^2)}
{(n-k+1)(n-k+2)}.
\end{align*}
Then, proceed to check the following equation holds:
$$F_j(n+2,k)-((n+1)^2-j^2)((n+3)^2-j^2)F_j(n,k)=G_j(n,k+1)-G_j(n,k).$$
Summing over all integers $k$ (bearing $\binom{a}b=0$ when $b<0$ or $b>a$), we gather the identity
$$\sum_{k=j}^{n+2} F_j(n+2,k)=\sum_{k=j}^n F_j(n,k). \tag1\label{484984_1}$$
It can be routinely checked that $\sum_{k=j}^{j+1}F_j(j+1,k)=0$, i.e. $n-j$ is odd with $n=j+1$. Since $n+2-j$ is odd iff $n-j$ is odd, it follows from \eqref{484984_1} that in such a case
$$\sum_{k=j}^nF_j(n,k)=(n+j+1)!(n-j+1)!\cdot 
f_{n,j}\left(\frac14\right)=0$$
as desired.
To address Fedor's question and after the facts from above (Hjalmar Rosengren's answer), we record the explicit formulation of $P_{n,j}(x)$ in non-hypergeometric formulation:
$$f_{n,j}(x)=\binom{n}j\binom{n+j}j
\left(\sum_{m=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n-j}2\rfloor}
(-x)^m(1-4x)^{\frac{n-j-2m}2}
\frac{\binom{n-j}{2m}\binom{2m}m}{\binom{m+j}j}\right)^2.$$

Thanks @T. Amdeberhan for your insightful conjecture! I also came across a similar guess but didn't formulate it as this explicit, so I think your conjecture should be valid. However, would you mind explaining where does the term (1-4x) come from in your conjecture? That might be helfpful for my proof next step.

For what it worth, $(-1)^jf_{n,j}$ is the coefficient of $v^js^n$ in $(s+(x+v)^2/v)^n(1+s)^{-n-1}$, possibly, some change of variables in Lagrange inversion style helps. Do you have a guess of the coefficients of $P_{n, j}$?

@FedorPetrov: at the time, I was not able to guess the coefficients.

@LeftHand: I've now added some pointers for the presence of the factor $1-4x$.
